# Connect to in-memory HSQL database (launched by Spring) from another client

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hsqldb, in-memory-database

I created a HSQL database with the following Spring configuration:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL">
    <jdbc:script location="resources/sql/schema.sql"/>
    <jdbc:script location="resources/sql/test-data.sql"/>
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

Everything works fine (for once)! I'd like to connect the same instance of that database from another client (I'm using database support from IntelliJ Ultimate) to alter/monitor the state of some tables for development reasons. Is it possible? How? If not, are there any alternatives/workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. HSQL database opened in embedded mode are opened in exclusive mode and can only be used from one single JVM.

There are different alternatives :

- the Spring application could implement a protocol to allow administrative supervision of the database
- you can use the database in server mode instead of embedded mode

In server mode, there is one dedicated application that opens the database in exclusive mode (the server), and then any client application connects to the server. But you can no longer use `<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL">` because it is a true jdbc server.

Comment: Note that to run HSQLDB in server mode (which allows connections from external clients), you don't need to start it in a separate process.  You can embed it in your application by instantiating an `org.hsqldb.server.Server` object.